# Why is typescript insisting on a type that is implied?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

In the line directly after `@ts-ignore`, I add a new key-value pair to an object that previously looked like this: `{id:string, text:string}`

As you can see here:

[image: this image]

Webstorm tells me that the type is supposedly `{id:string, text:string}`

I am wondering, why TypeScript insists on this?
I never declared that the object has to have only those two values.

**Code and Background**

```js
    const goals = COURSE_DATA.map((course) => {
        // @ts-ignore
        course.goals.forEach(g => g.course = course.title)
        return course.goals;
      }).reduce((accGoals, curGoals) => {
        let updatedGoals = curGoals;
        for (let goal of curGoals){
          updatedGoals.concat(goal);
        }
        return accGoals.concat(updatedGoals);
      }, [])
```

The purpose of this function is to take goal object arrays from their parent Course objects and coat them to a goals object array.
Basically turn **[**{[**{}**]}**]** to **[{}]**

FYI here's a peak into the parent object array:

```js
const COURSE_DATA = [
    {
        id: 'c1', title: 'Ionic + React - The Practical Guide', enrolled: new Date("03/05/2121"), goals: [{
            id: "c1g1",
            text: "Complete Course"
        }, {
            id: "c1g2",
            text: "Learn Something"
        }]
    },
]
```

Later on, I decided the final goals array need to contain the parent course name for each goal:

```
 // @ts-ignore
        course.goals.forEach(g => g.course = course.title)
```

the code does just that with `@ts-ignore`, but I'd like to understand why TypeScript complains, that there is no key of course in the object and why apparently there should be.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwgeQKoCUDKBRA%20gEQIIAqeMAvDANoCwAUDHTAN430swCWAJgFwwDkwARl4AaGFDZQANgFMevAJLg2wGAGoYKaQENgsALQwCAC2kwACgCcd44FskwA4gFdO0kTGlgLISTO4wwaQB3GBwtKGkACgAiAAYAZgB6WIBWRIAmAUzogEpRAHMQOwgeciZaVkrOHmjBfIFo4WZK1giADygauBAAWwAHGQj4ECcLCGlo5sqAX1FyltZqmFqBfPTGqYWxaQ6agBltCzAYNF7pKCM2MHzJipmAXU3ZmkfqGlBIWELi0nhkdGw%20CIADoelo%20pFIqBRuMcqQAHyMTaJRIwAACUAgejY%20TAIAs0k20LG0mB30kEGBADN8RgdEZIvkETB8sDieNfuzSeIpNIcpsCVBRscuWSihSANw0aY5YEEjhOYBRSI6YAOcUQUTAUbq4pwkiI%20b0QYwJx9DjhaQcXUUzk6jVSu4wGkWGCRE3kmAgKkwbUWG0QHJGypmi0Ra0atngWxQRninKOljTTYwQXCmCqgNRsAxyKhy0RvWO2YUe45IA)

Comment: As a side note: `updatedGoals.concat(goal);` will not do anything. It combines two arrays but it just returns a new one. However, that array is never used and thus just discarded.

Comment: before, I just had ´´´return updatedGoals;´´´ but that resulted in the final goals array only having the goals of the last parent object (course).

Comment: while trying to recreate it, I also tried ```updatedGoals = updatedGoals.concat(goal);``` inside the for loop... but that just resulted in the final goals array having the goals of the last course twice. I would love to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is infering the type from your `COURSE_DATA` object. Since it's defined explicit it assumes that this is also the exact typed structure of your object. If you want it to be more flexible use an interface to declare extra fields.

If you want to access a `title` and `course` field you should define its types somewhere anyway, that is the whole idea of TypeScript. Otherwise you are just popping in and out of the type system, which doesn't make a lot of sense if you think about it.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I'd just use it where I need to. Where I want to be specific about types or prevent future bugs. COURSE_DATA is just dummy data anyway.

Comment: regarding implicit/explicit. Isn't const car = "BMW" implicit and const car: string = "BMW" explicit?
Why then is COURSE_DATA, or to be precise, an object inside COURSE_DATA explicit?

Comment: There isn't really a difference. Typescript will infer the string type. It is implicit, yes, but for TypeScript it's the same.
If you want to use a type system just in some places of your app you might be better off using the flow type system.

Comment: but you can have some .tsx files no? I use some ionic components. And I want to implement ts more and more with the new functionality I add. 
Are you thinking of specific downsides?

Answer (score 0):

This updated code no longer requires @tsignore:

```ts
const goals = COURSE_DATA.map((course) => {
    return course.goals.map((goals) => {
        return {...goals, course: course.title}
    });
  }).reduce((accGoals, curGoals) => {
    let updatedGoals = curGoals;
    for (let goal of curGoals){
      updatedGoals.concat(goal);
    }
    return accGoals.concat(updatedGoals);
  }, [])
```

Comment: Please, do not use answers for follow-up questions - you can ask a new one. Also it would be nice if you add explanations for other readers